# LDAP attribute to filter built-in or default OUs in AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap

To reduce clutter in a selector GUI element I need a way to
tell OUs that ship with AD and Exchange by default (builtins, schema
defined, security or whatever) from such that the admin
created to organize their domain. E. g. the filter should
ignore OUs like:

- `OU=Domain Controllers,DC=example,DC=com`
- `OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=example,DC=com`

and only let those pass that were manually added.

So far I’ve been investigating the bits in the [`systemFlags:`
attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-systemflags).
The values are inconclusive though as some bits e. g. non-removability
are set for basic AD objects but don’t appear so for objects added
by Exchange.

I’m not sure if the attribute itself can be present in user
defined OUs. If not, that would be a sufficient signal to
base the filter on. `[MS-ADTS]` lists it as optional though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter by OU in an LDAP query, since a query cannot do partial matches on the `distinguishedName` (e.g. this won't work: `(!disginguishedName=*OU=Domain Controllers*)`)

If you want to exclude objects in certain OUs, you have two options:

1. Do it after the query, in your own code, where you can do partial comparisons on the `distinguishedName`, or
2. Make separate searches in the OUs that you *do* want. You can set the search root in each query to the OU you want, then repeat that for every OU you want to include.

Depending what you are trying to search for and the number of results, the first method might be faster than the second.

Comment: a) The filtering is not performed in an LDAP query. LDAP is merely the interface to AD. b) The filtering layer is already implemented. I’m asking **what LDAP attributes allow distinguishing builtin AD OUs from user defined ones**.

Comment: There are none. But even if you could, the `Microsoft Exchange Security Groups` OU isn't a built-in OU. It gets created when a domain is prepped for Exchange.